# How to integrate dot-components (React) library to Angular 15 application

Tags: reactjs, angular

Hello can you help with integration https://www.npmjs.com/package/@digital-ai/dot-components this (React) library to Angular v.15 application.

app-switcher-wrapper.jsx

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnChanges, OnDestroy, SimpleChanges, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {DotAppSwitcher, DotThemeProvider} from '@digital-ai/dot-components';

const containerElementName = 'dotAppSwitcherContainer';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-switcher',
    template: `<span #${containerElementName}></span>`
})
export class CustomReactComponentWrapperComponent implements OnChanges, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(containerElementName, {static: true}) containerRef!: ElementRef;


    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        this.render();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.render();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.containerRef.nativeElement);
    }

    private render() {

        const activeApp = {
            name: 'Continuous Testing'
        }

        const args = {
            open: true,
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
            <DotThemeProvider>
                <DotAppSwitcher activeApp={activeApp} {...args}/>
            </DotThemeProvider>
            ,
            this.containerRef.nativeElement
        )
        ;
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="main-view">
    <app-switcher></app-switcher>
</div>
```

I got a lot of errors witch related to depemdencies.

Part of errors:

./node_modules/@digital-ai/dot-components/index.esm.js:11:0-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs' in 'C:\Workfolder\react-integrated\node_modules@digital-ai\dot-components'

./node_modules/@digital-ai/dot-components/index.esm.js:12:0-53 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/updateLocale' in 'C:\Workfolder\react-integrated\node_modules@digital-ai\dot-components'

./node_modules/@digital-ai/dot-components/index.esm.js:15:0-35 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/utc' in 'C:\Workfolder\react-integrated\node_modules@digital-ai\dot-components'

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs/AdapterDayjs.js:3:0-33 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs' in 'C:\Workfolder\react-integrated\node_modules@mui\x-date-pickers\AdapterDayjs'

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs/AdapterDayjs.js:4:0-49 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear' in 'C:\Workfolder\react-integrated\node_modules@mui\x-date-pickers\AdapterDayjs'

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs/AdapterDayjs.js:5:0-69 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat' in 'C:\Workfolder\react-integrated\node_modules@mui\x-date-pickers\AdapterDayjs
'

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs/AdapterDayjs.js:6:0-65 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/localizedFormat' in 'C:\Workfolder\react-integrated\node_modules@mui\x-date-pickers\AdapterDayjs'

./node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs/AdapterDayjs.js:7:0-53 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dayjs/plugin/isBetween' in 'C:\Workfolder\react-integrated\node_modules@mui\x-date-pickers\AdapterDayjs'